# How to push an object into and array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm very new to react, I'm currently using a floating point with several options and depending on the option selected some info will be inserted into an array which then will display it on a card that will appear on the screen.

Below is the code for the floating action:

```
<FloatingAction
    showBackground = {false}
      actions={actions}
      
      onPressItem={ id => {

        switch (id) {
          case 1:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo A"
            }
            console.log(infoAnexo);
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
             
            }))            
            break;
          case 2:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo B"
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
            }))     
            break;
          case 3:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo C"
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
            }))     
            break;
          case 4:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo D"
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
            }))     
            break;
          case 5:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo E"
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
            }))     
            break;
          case 6:
            infoAnexo = {
              "name":"Anexo F"
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              categories: [...prevState.categories, infoAnexo]
            }))     
            break;

        }

        console.log(categories);
        
      }}
    />
```

Here are the actions that the floating point has

```
const actions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Añadir Anexo A",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_A",
    position: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Añadir Anexo B",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_B",
    position: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Añadir Anexo C",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_C",
    position: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Añadir Anexo D",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_D",
    position: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Añadir Anexo E",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_E",
    position: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    text: "Añadir Anexo F",
    icon: require("../assets/images/ic_accessibility_white.png"),
    name: "btn_anexo_F",
    position: 6,
  },
```

Here's the card that will be displayed on screen

```
<ScrollView
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={{ paddingVertical: theme.sizes.base * 2}}
    >
      <Block flex={false} row space="between" style={styles.categories}>
        {categories.map(category => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={category.name}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Explore', { category })}
          >
            <Card center middle shadow style={styles.category}>
              <Badge margin={[0, 0, 15]} size={50} color="rgba(41,216,143,0.20)">
                <Image source={category.image} />
              </Badge>
              <Text medium height={20}>{category.name}</Text>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
        
      </Block>
      
    </ScrollView>
```

And my array which currently is empty

```
 const categories = [];
```

Right now I'm trying to debug using console log but it prints an empty array. Help needed for this.

Edit: Rest of the code below

```
    class Browse extends Component {
  state = {
    active: 'Informes',
    categories: [],
  }
  

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ categories: this.props.categories });
  }

  handleTab = tab => {
    const { categories } = this.props;
    const filtered = categories.filter(
      category => category.tags.includes(tab.toLowerCase())
    );

    this.setState({ active: tab, categories: filtnpered });
  }

  renderTab(tab) {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const isActive = active === tab;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={`tab-${tab}`}
        onPress={() => this.handleTab(tab)}
        style={[
          styles.tab,
          isActive ? styles.active : null
        ]}
      >
        <Text size={16} medium gray={!isActive} secondary={isActive}>
          {tab}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```

Comment: where is the code that sets up the initial state with the categories? It looks like you've only posted the `render` functions when the state handlers might be the problem.

Comment: Just made the edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to know how to push an object into an array.
You can do this by below ways.

`categories.push(object)`

OR

// This method use to merge 2 arrays and create one but to add object you can use this like below.

categories = `categories.concat([object])`

Note: When we re-assign the variable must be `let` type not `const`.

Comment: I have tried this already, I'm thinking that the problem relies on the state as the user above mentioned, I have made an edit with the whole code.

Comment: Is your `this.props.categories` having data or it's empty?